# I have just recently upgrade to Laravel 10 from Laravel 5.8, i managed to successfully upgrade it, but i cant log in into the system

Tags: laravel, project, upgrade

I can enter into the login page of the system, but after inserting email and password, i cant get any further and when i inspect it says
"VM114:5 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated."

[While the logs of the system is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XgAc.png) 
Any ideas what could be wrong? this is my first time upgrading a project, so i didn't know what happen

Comment: if your project has been upgrade from laravel 5 to 10 which is that mean major upgrade, i think there is many file/class/function was deprecated. so it's not recommended for major upgrade. if you have more times, it's might be a good if you can step by step refactor your code to laravel 10 version code

Comment: yep, the system has been used for long time, and right now, there's new feature need to add on the system, and thus i have no choice but to upgrade it. Its progressing along fine right now, change from webpack to vite and right now restructuring the whole system to 'modernize' it